# XElement with colon in the name doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, xelement

i'm trying to make something like :

```
new XElement("media:thumbnail", new XAttribute("width", ""))
```

but i doesn't work, and i got a error because of the colon ':'.

does anyone know how can I solve the problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not how you create an `XName` with a namespace.

You should create an `XNamespace` with the right URI, and then you can create the right `XName` easily - personally I use the `+` operator. So:

```
XNamespace media = "... some URI here ...";
XElement element = new XElement(media + "thumbnail", new XAttribute("width", "");
```

To use a specific namespace *alias*, you need to include an attribute with the xmlns namespace, which can be in a parent element.

Here's a complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XNamespace ns = "http://someuri";
        var root = new XElement("root", 
                                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "media", ns),
                                new XElement(ns + "thumbnail", "content"));
        Console.WriteLine(root);        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<root xmlns:media="http://someuri">
  <media:thumbnail>content</media:thumbnail>
</root>
```

Obviously you need to use the *right* namespace URI though...

Comment: Hi @jon , I did it but my input is <thumbnail xmlns="media" width="">

Comment: @AdamB: That suggests you're using `media` as your namespace *URI*, which is almost certainly incorrect. Read my answer carefully, including the example.